# Ubuntu Camera: VIDIOC_STREAMON error 28, No space left on device

Tags: camera, bandwidth, depth, bus, uvc

I have a depth camera which outputs 5MP RGB image stream. When trying to use this camera, I got an error message:

```
VIDIOC_STREAMON error 28, No space left on device
```

The specification of the camera says I need a USB 3.0, which I do have, and the camera uses both RGB and Depth stream.

Here's the output of "lsusb"

```
    Bus 002 Device 019: ID 0b05:182c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
    Bus 002 Device 018: ID 0b05:182d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
    Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0bda:0401 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
    Bus 001 Device 009: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
    Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bda:5401 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL 8153 USB 3.0 hub with gigabit ethernet

The output of "dmesg -n 50" is :

[ 1535.643456] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 1535.943470] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 1536.243469] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 1536.972591] usb 2-3.1: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[ 1536.972595] usb 2-3.1: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 10
[ 1828.081983] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ 1828.434872] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS Xtion2 RGB (0b05:182d)
[ 1828.434876] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 1828.434878] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 1828.635409] input: ASUS Xtion2 RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1:1.0/input/input83
[ 1828.642270] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS Xtion2 Depth (0b05:182c)
[ 1828.642277] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 1828.642281] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 1828.646964] input: ASUS Xtion2 Depth as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.2/2-3.2:1.0/input/input84
[ 1828.649096] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 1828.649098] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[ 2010.073664] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS Xtion2 RGB (0b05:182d)
[ 2010.073669] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 2010.073671] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 2010.273866] input: ASUS Xtion2 RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1:1.0/input/input85
[ 2010.327318] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS Xtion2 Depth (0b05:182c)
[ 2010.327320] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 2010.327321] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 2010.331978] input: ASUS Xtion2 Depth as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.2/2-3.2:1.0/input/input86
[ 2010.688232] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2010.988243] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2011.288244] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2011.588260] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2011.888286] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2012.192254] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2012.492299] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 2013.217647] usb 2-3.1: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[ 2013.217656] usb 2-3.1: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 10
[ 3827.127184] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS Xtion2 RGB (0b05:182d)
[ 3827.127188] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 3827.127189] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 3827.327948] input: ASUS Xtion2 RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1:1.0/input/input87
[ 3827.404875] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS Xtion2 Depth (0b05:182c)
[ 3827.404879] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 3827.404881] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 3827.409851] input: ASUS Xtion2 Depth as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.2/2-3.2:1.0/input/input88
[ 3827.777065] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3828.077111] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3828.377078] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3828.677125] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3828.977091] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3829.277098] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_LEN) UVC control 3 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3829.577147] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 2 on unit 3: -110 (exp. 2).
[ 3830.307050] usb 2-3.1: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[ 3830.307053] usb 2-3.1: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 10
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error with ASUS Xtion2 depth camera on Ubuntu 16.04. The following worked for me.

- Connect your camera to USB 2.0 port with USB 3.0 cable.
- `sudo rmmod uvcvideo`
- `sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=640`

Now you should be able to run SimpleViewer successfully.

Comment: Interesting. How would a USB 2.0 port be able to stream high resolution video though?

Comment: is there any update on this? I met same problem last here and been in contact with Asus for very long time, without any success.. now they released updates (last one three days ago), but still the problem persist!